# What tool can I use to allow internal comunication in my network?

Tags: windows

My network is a fully Microsoft stack. I have Windows Server 2003 server.

What tool can I install on clients so they can talk internally without accessing outside?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a internal self hosted IM solution then I would check out http://www.igniterealtime.org/

This is what we use  at our office, its free, stable, and not too crazy to setup. If you really want to keep everything internal then this would be a good way to go. You can then use Pidgin or Spark (the client developed by this company) to chat internally.

Comment: raaaaaagh you beat me to it.

Comment: Also, to expand on a few points of David's answer: (1) Bonjour is great for simple ad-hoc communication on the same LAN, (2) If you need something more robust, like authentication and a bit more, an XMPP server is better. (3) You can use ANY compliant XMPP client if you run an XMPP server. A few examples off the top of my head: Spark, Pidgin, PSI, Swift, Pandion, and more.

Comment: Also, David, he can't use Spark before he uses OpenFire, or another XMPP Server.

Comment: Yeah, i should have clarified that. We use OpenFire as the server then most of our Windows users run the Spark client to access, while those of us on Linux run Pidgin.

Comment: Pidgin works well from Windows as well.  Spark occasionally crashes with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour from Apple, and Pidgin IM using the Bonjour protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Pop Messenger by Lead Mind](http://www.leadmind.com/) in the past and I liked it although it doesn't stack up so well against the other solutions already listed here, especially since it isn't free. I believe it uses UDP to communicate and uses UDP broadcast when you want to send a message to all clients at once. Unless something has changed since the time I used it, it does not require or make use of a client/server architecture.